# Is it possible to prevent a child method from running by using 'return' in the base class method when overriding?

Tags: c#, return, overriding

It must be a weird question, but why this logic below doesn't work?

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        base.Method();        // If this calls 'return;' here,
        print("still here");  // then why this is still running?
    }
}
```

What happens to the 'return' here? Why the program skips it?

Comment: There is no `return` there. simple as that

Comment: @MichaelRandall That is really confusing to me. Is there any way to prevent the child class method from continuing running from the base class other than adding an if statement with return in the method of the child class?

Comment: if you don't want to run the bass method, don't do this  `base.Method(); `

Comment: Return in anything you call just returns from what you called.  It doesn't make the caller return too.  If you called some unrelated external function that contains a return would you expect that return to affect the caller?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yeah, I know, I just wanted to make a check in the base class instead of having such check in each child class, that's all.

Comment: @DaveS Yeah, I see now.

Comment: Scope of "return" is inside Method only. To prevent execution write "return" just after calling the base method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `return` there. simple as that

A *method* will execute until it hits a `return`, the end of the method, or throw's an *exception*. In your case there is no return

```
base.Method();         // do something
print("still here");   // do something else
// end of method, stop doing stuff
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values)

> A method is a code block that contains a series of statements. A
>   program causes the statements to be executed by calling the method and
>   specifying any required method arguments. In C#, every executed
>   instruction is performed in the context of a method.

[Return values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values)

> The return keyword also stops the execution of the method. If the
>   return type is void, a return statement without a value is still
>   useful to stop the execution of the method. Without the return
>   keyword, the method will stop executing when it reaches the end of the
>   code block.

**A great clarifying comment from [Dave S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287427/dave-s)**

The return just returns from the function / method you called back to the caller. Return in a called function / method does not make the caller itself return. The fact that the method is in the base class is irrelevant.

Comment: to clarify, the return just returns from the function / method you called back to the caller.  Return in a called function / method does not make the caller itself return.  The fact that the method is in the base class is irrelevant.

Comment: @DaveS if you don't mind i added that, as it was well explained

Comment: Not at all, making an answer better helps everyone.